# Gulp watch doesn't not compile my .scss at each modification

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I encounter a problem with Gulp, I can not compile my .scss at each modification. When I run  "gulp watch" and make changes in my css, nothing happens.

`gulp css` works, `gulp watch` doesn't work.

Yet everything looks good.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks !

```
// Requires
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
// var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


// tâche CSS = compile vers knacss.css et knacss-unminified.css
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/assets/css/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(rename('knacss.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/css/'))
    .pipe(rename('style.css'))
    //.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(minifycss())
    //.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/css/'));
});

// Watcher
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['./src/assets/css/*.scss'], ['css']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['css']);
```

Comment: You are only watching *.scss files in /src/assets/css. Not in subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gulp watch doesn't not compile my .scss at each modification

### That's because you don't tell it to.

You are only watching `*.scss` files in `./src/assets/css`, not in subfolders.

To include subfolders, use this syntax:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['./src/assets/css/**/*.scss'], ['css']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! Works perfectly :)

Comment: No proplem, so it's also worth an upvote for being "useful"?

Answer (score 0):

try with something like.

```
//SASS task
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    var sassPath = {
        cssSrc: ['./src/assets/css/*.scss'], cssDest: './src/assets/css/'
    };
    gulp.src(sassPath.cssSrc)

      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(sassPath.cssDest))
      .pipe(livereload());
});
```

and then in your watch:

```
// Watcher
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['./src/assets/css/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```

and:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass','css']);
```